# my controller class cant found the class controller laravel 9

Tags: laravel

the error is this
Class "app\Http\Controllers\Controller" not found

my code is like this for the controller

```
<?php

namespace app\Http\Controllers;

use app\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param NA
     * @return view
     */
    public function index() {
        return view('users');
    }

    /**
     * @param request
     * @return response
     */
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $request = $request->all();
        $request['password'] = Hash::make($request['password']);

        $user = User::create($request);
        
        if ($user) {
            Alert::success('Success', 'anda berhasil mendaftar');
            $user->save();
            return redirect('/login');
            
        }
        else {
            Alert::error('Failed', 'gagal meregristrasi');
            return back();
        }
    }

}
```

this is the route that is use
Route::post('/register', [UserController::class, 'store'])->name('users.store');
Route::get('/register', function () {
return view('register');
});

the error is when i register how can i fix the class not found? the controller class is in the folder

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Controller class that UserController extends doesn't have the same namespace to UserController.

Try using namespace with App prefix instead

In UserController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
```

In web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
```

Comment: Check app\Http\Controllers folder to see whether there is a class called Controller